# not showing all results

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m trying to get data from all collaborators on a certain month. The problem is that if there's no data on that month on a certain department i won't get the row with that department.

This is the query i'm trying to work.

```
SELECT t1.ano, t1.mes,t1.departamento_id, t1.departamento_nome, tempo_extra, tempo_ativo, tempo_extra/tempo_ativo AS volume_extra
FROM (
SELECT YEAR(`data`) AS ano, MONTH(`data`) AS mes, departamentos.id AS departamento_id, departamentos.nome AS departamento_nome, SUM(tempo) AS tempo_extra
FROM rh.aprovacoes
LEFT JOIN rh.colaboradores ON colaboradores.id=aprovacoes.colaborador_id
LEFT JOIN rh.departamentos ON departamentos.id=colaboradores.departamento_id
WHERE (tipo = 'BH' OR tipo = 'HE') AND estado=1 AND YEAR(aprovacoes.`data`) = 2016 AND MONTH(aprovacoes.`data`) = 1
GROUP BY colaboradores.departamento_id, MONTH(`data`)
ORDER BY departamentos.nome ASC
        ) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT YEAR(`data`) AS ano, MONTH(`data`) AS mes, departamentos.id AS departamento_id, departamentos.nome AS departamento_nome, SUM(ativo) AS tempo_ativo
FROM rh.processamento
LEFT JOIN rh.colaboradores ON colaboradores.id=processamento.colaborador_id
LEFT JOIN rh.departamentos ON departamentos.id=colaboradores.departamento_id
WHERE YEAR(processamento.`data`) = 2016 AND MONTH(processamento.`data`) = 1
GROUP BY colaboradores.departamento_id, MONTH(`data`)
        ) AS t2 ON t1.departamento_id = t2.departamento_id
ORDER BY departamento_nome ASC;
```

I want to show the fields tempo_extra, tempo_ativo and volume_extra equal 0 if i won't get any data.

Comment: When left join, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, regular inner join result is returned.)

Comment: Didn't understand. Can you show me how?

Comment: The column `tempo_extra` is in `t1` whereas `tempo_ativo` is in `t2`. If you want to show them anyways, then you might wanna use `full join` or its equivalent in `mysql`.

Comment: I don't think there's full join or equivalent in mysql.

Comment: maybe it's easier if i show this query. `SELECT colaboradores.nome AS colaborador_nome, SUM(tempo) AS tempo_extra
FROM rh.aprovacoes
LEFT JOIN rh.colaboradores ON aprovacoes.colaborador_id=colaboradores.id
WHERE (tipo = 'BH' OR tipo = 'HE') AND estado=1 AND YEAR(aprovacoes.`data`) = 2016 AND MONTH(aprovacoes.`data`) = 1
GROUP BY colaboradores.id, YEAR(`data`), MONTH(`data`)
ORDER BY colaboradores.nome ASC;`

I want to show all existing `colaborador_nome` with `tempo_extra` null or as 0 if `aprovacoes` table has no results with that `colaborador_id`